# What is a DLL_SYMBOL?

Tags: c, header, symbols

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I found DLL_SYMBOLs statement in a header file:

```
 DLL_SYMBOL void mmi_print_info(mmi_info_t *m);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_get_menu_text(int sockfd, char *buf, int buf_len, int timeout);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_send_menu_answer(int sockfd, char *buf, int buf_len);
 DLL_SYMBOL UDPContext *mmi_broadcast_client_init(int port, char *iface);
 DLL_SYMBOL void mmi_broadcast_client_exit(UDPContext *s);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_poll_for_menu_text(UDPContext *s, mmi_info_t *m, int timeout);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_open_menu_session(char *uuid, char *iface,int port, int cmd);
 DLL_SYMBOL void mmi_close_menu_session(int s);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_cam_reset(char *uuid, char *intf, int port, int slot);
 DLL_SYMBOL int mmi_cam_reinit(char *uuid, char *intf, int port, int slot);
```

Are this special statements?

Comment: This must be a locally defined macro. As far as I know, there is no official symbol like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't look like ONE macro. This are than several with the same name, isn't it?

Comment: `DLL_SYMBOL` appears to be a macro that defines a certain, local calling convention - it is not a standard one like cdecl, stdcall and friends. Search for its definition in the included header file(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a macro. Many libraries have a macro to specify the calling convention of their public functions in the public `.h` file, the one that the client coude will include to use the library.

Yours is probably a Windows library. In Windows, any function to be used from a DLL should be declared with `__declspec(dllimport)`, so that the proper code to call the DLL is generated. So that is probably what your macro expands to. If you look around the header files of the library you'll find something like:

```
#define DLL_SYMBOL __declspec(dllimport)
```

An interesting related issue is that when you are compiling a DLL in Windows, public functions should be declared with `__declspec(dllexport)`. So most libraries use the same header files for import and export the public functions, and define the macro with something like:

```
#ifdef COMPILING_MY_LIBRARY
#define DLL_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_SYMBOL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And then, when compiling the library they define the macro `COMPILING_MY_LIBRARY`.